# How do I eradicate Pseudoperonospora cubensis on roses?

Tags: diseases, roses

I have some roses that look like they are infected with [Pseudoperonospora cubensis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoperonospora_cubensis). I currently do not know how to treat this disease and would like a course of action. I have not applied any pesticides/fungicides as I do not know which one to use.

Comment: The disease you refer to targets cucumbers.  Please show us pictures of what your Rose has so we can diagnose

Comment: Hi! Are you still having this problem? If so, as @kevinsky said, we need some pictures of your roses in order to help you. If you've solved it, would you take a few minutes to write an answer describing what you did? It would be a help to the community. I hope your roses are all better!